# Affecting div:hover with another div

Tags: html, css

I'm making a gallery where when you hover over the main image, the thumbnails should become transparent. I would like to achieve this with pure CSS, but I'm not sure if that's possible.

CSS:

```
/* should affect thumbs but not main */
/* obviously this code wouldn't work */
#main:hover, #thumbs {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
  Hover over me to change #thumbs
</div>
<div id="thumbs">
  I change when you hover over #main
</div>
```

Is this possible using pure CSS?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure, just use the adjacent sibling selector:

```
#div1:hover + #div2 {
    ...
}
```

An example here: http://jsfiddle.net/6BfR6/94/

Comment: +1 amazing... did not even know this existed! http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200007a.html

Comment: Wow! Thanks! That's absolutely perfect! Just like the guy above me, I had no idea that existed. Perfect.

Comment: +1 I had no idea you could do this without Javascript.

Comment: +1 Everyone who didn't know about this... prepare to be dazzled! :-) http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

Comment: @andyb: It's listed there, though it's not a CSS3 selector - it's in the completed CSS 2.1 specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/selector.html#adjacent-selectors

Comment: @Nightfirecat, yes I know it's a 2.1 selector. I just wanted to show the _current_ full spec of selectors :-)

Comment: You can use the even more general `~` selector, and you can even target elements that appear to be *before* the hovered one in the DOM. See my [pure-CSS signal bar rating widget answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered/32470900#32470900).

Answer (score 0):

Only children of a selector can be affected.  Otherwise, you'll need to use javascript.

For instance:

```
div:hover #childDiv {
  background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> *#div1:hover + #div2 {
>       ...
>   }*

it works fine in IE 7, 8, 9 and 10. No need to any JS or onovermouse and **NOT ONLY** children of a selector can be affected.

Try the example Link of "Nightfirecat".

Answer (score -1):

even if it is, it will not work in IE :)

i would suggest using onmouseover event

however it is nice question and I am curious if someone has solution of doing it cross-browser via css

Comment: It doesn't need to work in IE, I already know how to write the fallback, but I don't think I'm going to bother with that. It's more of a personal site.

Comment: @rev: see solution provided by Nightfirecat. It is amazing and it works in IE 7 & 8 - i have tested

Comment: You can do this with CSS alone. See my [pure-CSS signal bar rating widget answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered/32470900#32470900), which shows you can alter the styling of elements that even (appear to) show up in the DOM *before* the hovered one.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're going to need some javascript for that.

Comment: You can do this with CSS alone. See my [pure-CSS signal bar rating widget answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered/32470900#32470900), which shows you can alter the styling of elements that even (appear to) show up in the DOM *before* the hovered one.

Comment: seriously?  Downvoting after 4 years?

Comment: It's as wrong now as it was back then. I just stumbled over the answer yesterday. I'm not a moderator who might read answers as they're posted; just a random user who landed here from a web search.

Comment: There's a clearly accepted answer from 4 years ago, but you decided to go on a crusade to downvote other answers?  You seriously need a better hobby.

Answer (score -1):

No. You would have to use Javascript.

Comment: You can do this with CSS alone. See my [pure-CSS signal bar rating widget answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered/32470900#32470900), which shows you can alter the styling of elements that even (appear to) show up in the DOM *before* the hovered one.